# Error Using Odashi/mteval : cannot open shared object file

Tags: machine-translation

I keep getting an error when trying to run the command `mteval-sentence -e BLEU RIBES -r ref.tok -h hyp1.tok` in Ubuntu. the Error is "mteval-sentence: error while loading shared libraries: libmteval.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Any tips?

Comment: how about trying `nltk.translate`? https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/develop/nltk/translate

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the mteval binary is unable to locate the shared objects, `libmteval.so.*` on this case. The solution is to add the path of the shared objects to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` system variable. To do so, first locate the path, which is by default `/usr/local/lib`, then execute the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
```

After that restart the shell before you run mteval again.